# Find Location of Iphone (GeoCoding)

Tags: iphone, geocoding

I am using  http://www.mobileorchard.com/hello-there-a-corelocation-tutorial/
for getting the location using Iphone.(It gives Latitude & Longitude)
Now i want the cities/zipcode based on these Latitude & Longitude in Iphone.
So please suggest me for the above.
Sample code/tutorial will be much better(if possible)...as I am very new to this Iphone development.

Thanks.

Comment: duplicate questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/geocoding+iphone

Answer (score 1):

You can use the builtin MKReverseGeocoder class in UIKit. You will however have to adhere to Googles license terms, e.g. that you have to show the results on a Google map, etc.

Alternatively you can use the various services available from [GeoNames](http://www.geonames.org/export/ws-overview.html), for your need especially the [postal code lookup](http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html#findNearbyPostalCodes) could be of interrest. They are provided both as xml and json formats. They have a lot less restrictive licens term than Google.

Comment: HI i have tried
http://ws.geonames.org/findNearbyPostalCodes?lat=47&lng=9 
for getting Zipcode by passing lat & lng.
But it's accuracy is very low....it is giving response in distances of 15-20 KM.
So please suggest me smthing more.
Thanks.